# maximum using completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics

Is it just me, or this problem does sound weird?

The Parks Department is fencing a rectangular dog-run (a place for dogs to exercise) in a local park. It will be 7 yards longer than 5 times its width. If the Parks Department has allocated 98 yards of prefabricated fence to this project, what are the dimensions of the maximum possible area for the dog-run? You must use completing the square to answer this question.

**Attempt:** I get too many equations. If the length is 7 + 5 times the width, then we have the following: $$l=7+5w$$ and the perimeter is $$ 98=2w+14+10w=12w+14$$ and we get the width. Where do I use completing the square? If I do not use the information about the length being 7 +5 times the width, then I get $$A=lw$$ and $$98=2l+2w$$ these equations will not give me a concave down quadratic, and hence no use calculating its vertex.

Thanks!

Comment: One might argue that the allocated $98$ yards of fence need not all be used so there is some room left for optimizaton, but it is obvious that more fence means more area in this setup and the use of completing the square for this problem should be punished with getting a job in the Parks and Recreaton Departement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your confusion, since, the constraints. To maximize area given that length is to be 7 more than 5 times the width, the length and width are *determinined* by using as much of the $98$ yards of fencing:

We have $\mathcal l = 7 + 5w\tag{1}$

So perimeter $98 = 2\mathcal l + 2w$ using  $(1)$ gives us $$2(7+5w) + 2w \implies 14 + 12 w = 98 \iff 12 w = 84 \iff w = 7$$

Then expanding on $A = \mathcal l\cdot w = (7 + 5w)w = 7w + 5w^2$

we have $$A = 7w + 5w^2 = 49 + 5\cdot 49 = 6\cdot 49 = 294\;\;\text{sq. yards}$$

Comment: $\huge\color{blue}{+☺+}$

Comment: @amWhy: nice clean write up. +1

Answer (score 1):

Solve $98=2l=2w$ for $l$ in terms of $w$ (or for $w$ in terms of $l$), then substitute into $A=lw$ to get the area as a function of a single variable. However, you'll find that the dimensions maximizing the area through this approach will be those of a square. This is, indeed, a bad problem. Where did you encounter it?

Comment: so there is no point of saying "it is 7 yards longer than 5 times its width"?

Comment: No, I think your original approach is the sensible one to take. Completing the square will not get you dimensions of the appropriate form ($l=7+5w$).